# ActionScript3 MouseEvent.CLICK not working with no errors

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

What i am trying to achieve is that when the cowboy is clicked he disappears. I have tried it with a trace comment as well and nothing shows when the cowboy is clicked.

When i run the program i get no errors. I can't figure out why.
Here's my code

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.ui.Mouse;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Callum Singh
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public var gun:crosshair;
        public var cowboy:enemy;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            gun = new crosshair();
            stage.addChild (gun);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCrosshair);

            cowboy = new enemy();
            cowboy.x = Math.random() * 600;
            cowboy.y = Math.random() * 400;
            stage.addChild (cowboy);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleShoot);
        }

        private function moveCrosshair(e:Event):void
        {
            gun.x = mouseX -120;
            gun.y = mouseY -115;

        }

        private function handleShoot(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (e.target == cowboy)
                {
                    cowboy.visible = false;
                }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add the listener to the **cowboy** object, and sometimes changing MouseEvent.CLICK to MouseEvent.**MOUSE_DOWN** helps.

```
cowboy.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleShoot);
```